# Organize by Month/Artist and Add Song Prices

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, group-by, e-commerce, nested-loops

I have created a functioning e-commerce platform where Members can buy songs. Everything works fine, But I would like to display the Total Revenue generated each Month by an Artist in my Index Page.

Currently I am able to group by Month & Artist, But I am struggling to create a method that adds all of the song prices to generate the Artist's Total Revenue.

**How can I add an Artist's Ordered Song Prices to generate that Months Total Revenue for that Artist?**

```
EX. of what I'd like:

Month 1 
  Artist1 ($Total Artist Revenue Month 1)  
    Album1                    ###List of Albums Corresponding to an Artist 
    --Song1 (10 0rders)          
    --Song3 (5 Orders)
    Album2 
    --Song5 (2 Orders)        ###Ordered Songs Corresponding to an Album 

Month 2  
  Artist2  ($Total Artist Revenue Month 2)
    Album1 
    --Song2 (1 Order)
  Artist3  ($Total Artist Revenue Month 2)
    Album3 
    --Song5 (1 Order)
```

MODELS

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :artist_id, :album_id, :user_id, :order_date

  belongs_to :song
  belongs_to :user

end

class Artist < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name

  has_many :albums
  has_many :songs, :through => :albums
  has_many :orders, :through => :songs

end

class Album < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :artist_id

  belongs_to :artist
  has_many :songs
  has_many :orders, :through => :songs

end

class Song < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :artist_id, :album_id, :title, :price

  belongs_to :album
  has_many :orders

end
```

CONTROLLERS

```
def index    
  ###Groups things by Month
  @orders = Order.find(:all, :order => 'order_date, id', :limit => 50)
end
```

VIEWS

```
<% @orders.sort.group_by { |order| order.order_date.beginning_of_month }.each do |month, orders| %>
  <h3><%= month.strftime('%B') %> </h3>   ###Groups all Orders by Month

  <% orders.group_by { |order| order.song.album.artist.name }.each do |artist, orders| %>
    <h4><%= artist %> </h4>    ###Groups all Artist with Orders

    ###I can display the price for each song....But
    ###How Can I Add These Values or place them into a New Array 
    ###So I can generate the total revenue? 
    <% orders.each do |order| %>      
      <%= order.song.price %>    
    <% end %>   

  <% end %>

<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could sum the prices of the orders in the view:

```
<% orders.each do |order| %>
  <%= order.song.price %>
<% end %>
<%= orders.map { |o| o.song.price }.sum %>
```

You could then move that logic into the `Artist` model:

```
class Artist
  # ...
  def total_revenue(orders)
    orders.map { |o| o.song.price }.sum
  end
  # ...
end
```

It might make more sense for `total_revenue` to sum all orders within a certain time frame, in which case ActiveRecord can handle the logic of computing order revenue, something along the lines of:

```
class Artist
  # ...
  def total_revenue(start_interval, end_interval = start_interval.end_of_month)
    songs.joins(:orders)
         .where(orders: { order_date: start_interval..end_interval })
         .sum(:price)
  end
  # ...
end
```

See [this](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Calculations.html#method-i-sum) for more information about summing columns with ActiveRecord.

Comment: dude your a life saver!! I have been trying to get this all day. Thanks :)